# How to map complex joins in JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f64c1/1/0

Here is an SQL fiddle that represents a simplified version of my problem (in reality there are a few more tables involved).

I already have the two tables mapped out as JPA entities and I know how to get query for rows from either table by searching on id, etc.

But how do I get complex results like shown in the sqlfiddle query? The relation between the main and details tables isn't just based on the id field in each, but also on a join back to the main table to find the date range to then join to the details table on (end_date).

Do I need to somehow map an endDate field in the entity class representing the main table and define the relationship with the details entity based on that? Do I need to write a similarly complex JPQL query with the constructor of some new java class to wrap the results? Or is this out of the scope of what JPA is supposed to be for?

```
select x.id, x.start_date, x.end_date, d.detail
from
(
  select mt.id, mt.start_date,
  (
    select mt_next.start_date from main mt_next
    where mt_next.id = mt.id and mt_next.start_date > mt.start_date
    order by mt_next.start_date asc limit 1
  ) as end_date
  from main mt
) x
left join details d on d.id = x.id 
  and d.detail_date >= x.start_date
  and (x.end_date is null or d.detail_date < x.end_date)
```

Comment: Present your classes, and what you want to achieve in your question. Linking to 3rd party sites for some other definition of a problem is not manageable here ... people have limited time, and also that could be deleted in the future rendering this question meaningless.

Comment: Didn't think about that. I've seen SQLFiddle all over this site but it makes sense that it might not be there forever. Added the SQL to my post.